# Skipping spaces and detecting end of line?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program that reads in the following (call this text block data1):

```
S T E L B M T F E Y D E E P S R T C I A E E 
N N E L I T R L B D E T A R E M U N E T Y L 
N O I T A N I M I R C N I F L E S S E N T A 
A U I D E W A R R A N T N U P R U S S E R P 
P G S G E A L P A P B A N P S A S S N M E A 
C O N S I T U T I O N D E E C W S O O H P D 
S V W D E L A N E E J A M E S M A D I S O N 
A E D E S N E G R J C U L T N O H L T I R A 
A R C E R R T R E E S B O N E E I D N N P R 
S N J U D I C I A L A S S E C O R P E U D I 
S M R A R A E B W B E S S M E O A U V P E M 
O E O I A I L N O U C D O D S S E N N I G R 
L N I D G Y T R C O M P E N S A T I O N N D 
D T O Z E H P Y N D R L E E A O H S C O I B 
I T P S U E T G O L U Z M M R B E H P I R T 
E O I E A R R S U U I B H A Y L L M S T F A 
R I N R E E E F U T L V Q U A R T E R I N G 
S I D B S R R D I Y E N I G M I A N A T I R 
S Q I S E B S C N S P E E C H R O T A E Y N 
D L C M I L I T I A F L R N C A T S S P S E 
R U T E D Y L E B I L C O H M L E T E S Y Y 
L S T R T E W Z L I O S A E N S A E I Y A L
AMENDMENT
ASSEMBLY
BAIL
BEARARMS
CITIZEN
CIVIL
COMPENSATION
CONGRESS
CONSITUTION
CONVENTIONS
DELEGATED
DOUBLEJEOPARDY
DUEPROCESS
ENUMERATED
FREEDOM
GOVERNMENT
ILLEGAL
INDICT
INFRINGED
JAMESMADISON
JUDICIAL
LAWSUIT
LIBEL
LIBERTY
LIFE
MILITIA
MIRANDA
NECESSARY
PEACEABLY
PEERS
PETITION
POWER
PRESS
PROBABLECAUSE
PROPERTY
PUNISHMENTS
QUARTERING
RELIGION
RIGHTS
SEARCH
SECURITY
SEIZURE
SELFINCRIMINATION
SLANDER
SOLDIERS
SPEECH
SPEEDY
TRIAL
UNREASONABLE
WARRANT
WITNESS
```

I know end of line is \0. I'm essentially trying to assign this whole thing to an array that's 50 x 50 (this is 22 x 22) and all other empty areas are just blank spaces (i.e. column 23, row 1 is just an empty space).

How do I read in the characters, SKIP the spaces, and detect the end of lines?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ROWS 50
#define COLUMNS 50

int main()
{
    int sizeOfGrid = 0;
    int rowNumber = 0;
    int colNumber = 0;
    /* */
    char letters[ROWS][COLUMNS];
    FILE *fp1 = fopen("data1","r");
    if (fp1)
    {
        for (rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < ROWS; rowNumber++)
        {
            for(colNumber = 0; colNumber < COLUMNS; colNumber++)
            {
                letters[rowNumber][colNumber] = ' ';
            }
        }
        /* Lets speak psuedocode here:
         * Search data1's first line
         * While character isn't end of line
         *  If character isn't a space,
         *      sizeOfGrid++ <--Count all the characters to get the dimensions.
         *      ^--Note that the width and height are locked together, i.e.
         *      an array with 18 width will have the same height as the width,
         *      so 18 width and 18 height.
         *  
         * While rowNumber and colNumber < (sizeOfGrid - 1)
         *  for rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < (sizeOfGrid - 1); rowNumber++
         *      for colNumber = 0; colNumber < (sizeOfGrid - 1); 
         *          letters[rowNumber][colNumber] gets the next character in data
         * */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

There are MULTIPLE files that need reading so I'd like to set it up to be as dynamic as possible, so sizeOfGrid will change when it opens data2 and data3; it essentially repeats itself for all three files.

Comment: `'\0'`, or NUL, or the null character, or zero is the terminator at the end of a C string, not the end of the line.

Comment: Alright then, what would I use in it's place?

Comment: When you read from the file, among the characters read will be the newlines in that file, probably a single `'\n'` at the end of each line (though in some cases there may be, e.g., `"\r\n"`, depending on the system and how you read). If you read C strings (e.g., with `fgets`) the string will _additionally_ be terminated with a `'\0'`. My suggestion is to ignore all whitespace (e.g., check with `isspace`).

Comment: Thing is though, which function do I use? That's mainly the big question. And there's more to it than that as you can see from the bottom of my post.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with `sizeOfGrid`? Is it supposed to have the width/height of the file that has been read at the end?

Comment: It's supposed to be used to determine the size of the grid files its reading. The three files have different grid sizes, but they are no larger than 50 x 50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after the clarification, here are my words for this:

My suggestion is using `fgetc` over everything else. Just like in many other cases, it is the most hassle-free option. `fgetc` gets the character that the caret/cursor is on in the file, advances the caret/cursor to the next position. Since you'll be issuing almost every character in the file anyway, it simply just perfectly fits to this case.

**One important remark:** `fgetc` returns an integer value. This is to ensure that it can properly handle the EOF (-1) error return.

All you have to do is to store the character that `fgetc` gives to you, check it if it is a space `' '` or a new line `'\n'` or a letter that you'd like to store, and do whatever you need to do with them.

Without modifying what you have done so far too much, here's one way to do it:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ROWS 50
#define COLUMNS 50

int main( )
{
    int sizeOfGrid = 0;
    int rowNumber = 0;
    int colNumber = 0;
    /* */
    char letters[ROWS][COLUMNS] = { 0 };  // { 0 } for the initialization of each element with zeros
    FILE *fp1 = fopen( "data1", "r" );

    int currentChar;        // <-- introduced this variable

    if ( fp1 )
    {
        for ( rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < ROWS; rowNumber++ )
        {
            for ( colNumber = 0; colNumber < COLUMNS; colNumber++ )
            {

                // fgetc gets the character that the cursor/caret is currently on
                // moves the cursor/caret to the next poisition inside the file
                currentChar = fgetc( fp1 );

                // if it was a space, continue
                // but decrease the colNumber by 1 first, because it will get increased
                if ( currentChar == ' ' ) {
                    colNumber--;
                    continue;
                }

                // if it was a new line ('\n' or 10, the same)
                // just break out back inside the rowNumber loop
                if ( currentChar == '\n' ) {
                    // break out of the nested loop if we were on the last row of the grid
                    if ( rowNumber == sizeOfGrid - 1 ) rowNumber = ROWS;
                    break;
                }

                // having advanced this far implies that we have a valid line
                // so... increase the sizeOfGrid by 1

                // detect the size of grid through the amount of letters on the first row
                if ( rowNumber == 0 ) sizeOfGrid++;
                letters[rowNumber][colNumber] = currentChar;
            }
        }

        /* Lets speak psuedocode here:
        * Search data1's first line
        * While character isn't end of line
        *  If character isn't a space,
        *      sizeOfGrid++ <--Count all the characters to get the dimensions.
        *      ^--Note that the width and height are locked together, i.e.
        *      an array with 18 width will have the same height as the width,
        *      so 18 width and 18 height.
        *
        * While rowNumber and colNumber < (sizeOfGrid - 1)
        *  for rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < (sizeOfGrid - 1); rowNumber++
        *      for colNumber = 0; colNumber < (sizeOfGrid - 1);
        *          letters[rowNumber][colNumber] gets the next character in data
        * */
    }

    // for testing
    /*for ( rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < sizeOfGrid; rowNumber++ ) {
        for ( colNumber = 0; colNumber < sizeOfGrid; colNumber++ ) {
            printf( "%c ", letters[rowNumber][colNumber] );
        }
        putchar( 10 );
    }
    getchar( );*/

    return 0;
}
```

It has a bunch of comments in it, hopefully won't leave any questions in your mind. In case there remains a confusion, feel free to ask.

**Edit #1:** Updated the code to work with the newly introduced data1 file structure, which has more than just the grid.

Comment: While it makes sense, I actually prefer to just read it from left to right if possible. Also, I think it'd be better to use while loops or if statements inside of them and only increment when it picks up an actual char that's not a space. Also what's putchar(10); do?

Comment: @MajorCooke `putchar( 10 );` puts the character `10` to the standard output, and character `10` is `'\n'`, new line. This thing does already read the file from left to right... You could do whatever you please, but in the end it will most likely do the exact same as this does. You could, for example, leave out that `colNumber--` inside the `if` and `colNumber++` at the end of the `for` parenthesis, and put down `++` right after the `colNumber` inside the square brackets at the end of the loop.

Comment: I've updated the top post, I thought I had included the list of words that swiftly follow after the giant puzzle but I hadn't. I now need to stop the program from reading in beyond the last part, which is why I had sizeOfGrid there to begin with.

Comment: @MajorCooke Can you guarantee that the amount of characters to be read on each line will be constant for the grid part, within a file? If yes, can you also guarantee that this will be a square grid?

Comment: No, that's the problem. It looks like I'd have to detect two characters together but then I'd be left two letters short, I think...

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that the end result will be the removal of all unneeded characters; that list of words is being used to "find" them within the grid which I think I can handle. I just need to be able to read in the grid, know where to stop, and then read in the words.

Comment: @MajorCooke I still am having hard times on understanding it... What is the `sizeOfGrid` meant to have as the value in the end? For example, can the grid be 15x25? In that case, what value should the `sizeOfGrid` have? Until now, I always have thought that the grid is to have the dimesions ABxAB all the time (square grid), and `sizeOfGrid` then would be `AB`.

Comment: No, the grid is hardlocked; the size of the width is the size of the height, a perfect square. sizeOfGrid is used to implement that, and help make a permanent separator between the grid, and the list of words.

Comment: @MajorCooke Okay, now I get it, I think. I have changed the code, so that it can handle the data1 file with more than just the grid. It works out here, it should be working out there as well. Question: The first row has `X` letters in it, is it guaranteed that the next row will also have `X` letters in it? Also, is it guaranteed that there will be `X` rows, each row having `X` letters in it? That is what I have understood from your words, hopefully I did not understand something wrong...

Comment: That is correct. Because it's the perfect square, it's not ever going to have one row OR column thats larger or smaller than another.

Answer (score 1):

Since it doesn't appear that you know the number of rows and columns (except by inspecting the file), you should read the entire line at once into a string `gets()` (or better `fgets()` since it allows a maximum line length). Then you can look for non-spaces (or alternatively, capital letters) in order to determine the width (and therefore height) of the matrix. Declare  the line as an array of `char` large enough for the longest line.

Comment: Never use or recommend the use of `gets`.

Comment: @Arkku, I agree which is why I included fgets(), but this is clearly an assignment and as a teacher, I know that you can't learn everything at once.

Comment: So why didn't you just say `fgets` without mentioning `gets`? `gets` isn't even standard in C11 anymore.

Comment: Would I use the fgets in one of my for loops, or the first while loop?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
int rowNumber = 0;
int colNumber = 0;
int c;
/* */
char letters[ROWS][COLUMNS];
FILE *fp1 = fopen("data1","r");

memset(&letters[0][0], 32, ROWS*COLUMNS);

if(fp1 == NULL){printf("Cannot open file"); return 0;}

while( (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF ){
    c = fgetc(fp);

    if(c == '\n'){
        if(rowNumber == ROWS - 1){printf("rowNumber = max \n"); break;}
        rowNumber++; colNumber = 0;
    }
    else if(c != ' '){
        if(colNumber == COLUMNS - 1){printf("colNumber = max \n"); break;}
        letters[rowNumber][colNumber] = (char)c; colNumber++;
    }
    else{;}
}
```

valter

Comment: You don't need to call `feof`, you can check `c == EOF`, the magic numbers `49` should be replaced with `(ROWS-1)` and `(COLUMNS-1)`, `32` with `' '`, and the empty `else{;}` can be removed (and even within it, the `;` does nothing). It also seems to me that `colNumber` will end up as zero if the last line ends with a newline.

Comment: @Arkku I know about the else is not needed but long ago i had a problem with if elseif when i didnt insert the else statement in the end. It became a habbit.

Comment: Seems like a bad habit to insert code that does nothing; rather learn why you had to insert it that one time and only insert it in that situation.